# minecraft mapping from tibia OTBM file

Tags: textures, minecraft-modding, modding, file-format, porting

I am new to minecraft modding but i program for a living and it looks quite simple to get around. I have this fantasy and a quick internet search shows im not the only one. For those of you who do not know tibia is an MMORPG first released in 1997. It is a 2d tile based game and i would like to see it in 3D. since it is a tile based game it fits nicely with the minecraft architecture. Tibia is a close sourced game but there is TibiaOT which is developed by the community and the map file format is OTBM (open tibia binary map). This is a set of 15 2D grids where each grid represents a floor or the height of the grid, the file comes with two more files with monster spawns and default item locations like chests.

There is a tibia texture pack for minecraft called "Tibian texture pack", so we got the materials covered.

all in all we have the following: a native tibia map and a minecraft texture pack

people have been building tibia maps manually for years now, it seems stupid because we have a binary file for the real map. what we need is a way to map the OTBM file to a minecraft map. i am looking for tools and any other tips a on how to digest the files into a minecraft map file. an explanation of minecraft map file format would also be very helpful.

Comment: Incidentally, this has been [shotgunned](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/minecraft-mapping-from-tibia-otbm-file) [across](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288936/minecraft-mapping-from-tibia-otbm-file) [multiple](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/194353/20456) sites.  That last one is Arqade 10K only, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Answer from [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/194374/30879)

> MCEdit is a tool for editing minecraft save file, I can write a filter for it that manipulates the MC saves. I can also read the OTBC file using the OT c++ modules and formatting them into XML then translating the XML into MCedit readable data and then injecting them into a minecraft save through a MCedit filter script.